# Redirect from login.jsp if already logged in

Tags: jsp, redirect, authentication

If registered user jumps to `login.jsp` I wish to redirect him to `youAreLoggedIn.jsp`.
Can this be made with `<navigation-rule>`? I know how to do this in PHP but not in JSP.
When user visits `login.jsp` it must check if user is logged in this I know how to check. But  how to trigger this action? Should I make a new servlet or what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common practice is to use a `Filter` for this. Just implement [`javax.servlet.Filter`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html), define it in `web.xml`, map it on an `url-pattern` of `/login.jsp` and write something like following in `doFilter()` method:

```
if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("user") != null) {
    // User is logged in, redirect to desired page.
    ((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect("youAreLoggedIn.jsp");
} else {
    // Do nothing, continue request.
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Simple as that. It of course assumes that the logged-in `User` is been put in the session scope as per the normal practices.

That said, `<navigation-rule>` is JSF specific, but you didn't state anything about JSF in your question nor the tags. Aren't you confusing things up?

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! `<navigation-rule>` I use for main menu and for errors. So I thought it would work with it.

Comment: In other words, you're actually using JSF? It's however strange that you keep mentioning JSP all the time. Please understand what JSP is for and what JSF is for and take this into account in future questions. There may be different ways to solve a particular problem depending on the fact whether you're using JSF or not.